# wp - can't change header image in admin section, using woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, header, woocommerce

I have a wordpress site built on woocommerce plugin, and i can't seem to change the header image when in admin:

appearance->header

When in that section, i try to change header section on nav menu on left and clicking save, but the site doesn't change to new header image.

Also I'm using the brewery theme:
http://themeforest.net/item/brewery-a-wordpress-theme-for-beer-makers/10941216

Comment: The theme you are using is premium one, shouldn't their support be helping you out? Alternatively try enabling debug mode and see if there are any errors that show when you save the header image.

Comment: well even under debug mode i don't see any errors...can you tell me where the submit button is posting to?  cause i can't seem to trace it, i checked javasript files as well...

Comment: that I am not sure of as I haven't used the theme. Your best bet is to contact the theme's support guys and ask them to help you out. This looks more of a theme issue then WordPress.

Comment: i can't even ask on their forums, says i need a purchase code, which i did not purchase but my client did...